# Connect a laptop HDD to another computer

Tags: windows-7, partitioning, permissions

I was wondering how to connect a laptop HDD to another computer, so that some examination on the HDD may be performed by the other computer?

The easier, the better, whether it is internal inside the other computer or external to it.

If connect externally, do I need to buy a laptop HDD enclosure? I have a desktop HDD enclosure, although it is not for laptop HDD.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the laptop hard drive is SATA and your PC has a SATA port, then all you have to do is connect it.  Easy as it gets.

A desktop HDD enclosure is made for a 3.5" drive, laptop drives are 2.5".  You can buy [brackets](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16817994072&nm_mc=KNC-GoogleAdwords&cm_mmc=KNC-GoogleAdwords-_-pla-_-NA-_-NA) to put in the enclosure for a better fit.

However, there are some great solutions out there such as [this](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16812200155&nm_mc=KNC-GoogleAdwords&cm_mmc=KNC-GoogleAdwords-_-pla-_-NA-_-NA).  I always carry one of these in my tool bag.

Answer (score 1):

No need for an external enclosure. What you want is a SATA/IDE to USB adapter. There are many vendors, it'll run you around $30. I've had good luck with Apricorn's products: http://www.apricorn.com/products/notebook-hard-drive-upgrade-kits/sata-wire-3.html